# redirect loop when redirecting to another page when logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am getting a redirect loop and I dont know why. I have this simple code being used so that if someone goes to default.aspx and is already logged in it should redirect them to inside.aspx. Why am I getting a redirect loop?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // if the user is already logged in
        {
            Response.Redirect("inside.aspx");
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:

both pages share a master page with the following code, this only goes off when the logoff control is pushed:

```
public partial class template : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        Session.Abandon();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the codebehind for inside.aspx look like? And what rewrite rules (if any) do you have?

Comment: The c# code behind inside.aspx is currently empty. I am new to asp.net but I looked up rewrite rules I don't believe I have done anything with that. Both pages to share a master page with code, I'll post it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the CodeFile reference for both files was the same. Silly mistake but if you have this problem make sure to check it!

Answer (score 1):

I assume your ask is when you are trying to logout, the page is redirecting to default page again. Reason is you are clearing the session after it is redirected, so the Session.Abandon() doesn't get called. But I don't know if your authentication is really dependent on Session.Abandon() in which case you will again see the redirect.

```
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
```

If you are using membership provider, check out the defaultUrl that can be configured to automatically redirect after the user is logged out. For manually triggering the logout, use FormsAuthentication.SignOut().